# Ocultar botón al iniciar sesión y cuando cierre volver a mostrarlo. Js y Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Alguien me podría ayudar, necesito hacer que un botón al iniciar sesión se quité y se mantenga oculto hasta cerrar sesión y no se como hacerlo. Js y Jquery.

Lo que quiero es que al darle click al botón desaparezca hasta que cierre sesión y que cuando cierre sesión vuelva a aparecer.

```
Elemento a ocultar hasta cerrar sesión Html
 <a class="btn btn-success login" id="login" href="<%= login === 'si' ? '/' : '/login' %>"><%= status %></a>
```

Javascript, lo esconde por un momento y lo muestra al iniciar sesión y eso no es lo que quiero, lo que quiero es  o mostrarlo hasta cerrar sesión.

```
$(function(){
    $('#login').click(function(){
      $('#login').hide();
    });
  })
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta es muy amplia, se podría hacer de infinidad de formas, te sugiero que muestres lo que has intentado, cómo manejas las sesiones y el código de tu HTML. Puedes leer [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Muchas Gracias por tu aporte, ya puse codigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero que tienes que saber, es que estás usando un enlace. Ese enlace al hacer click te va redireccionar a la url que le digas. Por lo que si haces click en ese enlace, la funcionalidad que tengas en el evento **click** de ese botón se la va saltar y no se va ejecutar.

Así que de buenas a primera yo te recomiendo usar un event.preventDefault(), para evitar que haga la redirección. [Aquí](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/event_preventdefault.asp) tienes más documentación al respecto.

Por lo pronto podrías hacer algo así:

```
     $(function(){
       $('#login').off().on('click',function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         $('#login').hide();
       });
     })
```

Así te aseguras que el evento **click** funcione.

Igualmente creo que tu problema de raíz si consigo adivinarlo, es que cuando te logueas, el botón de login sigue estando ahí. Y eso se soluciona tan fácil, como poniendo una clase css al botón y controlarlo por sesión, o simplemente poniéndole un **display:none** al elemento, si la sesión del usuario existe.

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Sería simplemente ponerle esa clase al elemento #login, si estás logueado. Si está deslogueado simplemente quitar la clase **hidden**. Eso lo puedes controlar en el html antes de pintar el botón.

Answer (score 0):

Qué código del lado del servidor estás utilizando?, según tu código yo lo haría así:

```
<%= login === 'si' ? '' : '<a class="btn btn-success login" id="login" href="/login"><%= status %></a>' %>
```

No sé bien que muestra **status** pero no lo necesitarías, salvo claro que cambie el texto por el idioma.